# Chrome extension preserve changes to the popup page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Chrome extension and I do not know how to make the changes to the popup page persistent. When I change the content of the popup page through JavaScript, all the changes get lost as soon as the popup window is closed.

Any idea on how I can make it so the changes (for instance text or colour changes) stay on the page for the duration of visiting a particular site?

Comment: The popup is created/destroyed when shown/closed so you'll have to use chrome.storage.local to store the values, then read them on start and apply to the page via DOM methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need to save the data you want to preserve (with chrome.storage or localstorage) and then reload it when launching the popup page.
Here is an exemple of usage from the official documentation :

```
chrome.storage.local.set({key: value}, function() {
  console.log('Value is set to ' + value);
});

chrome.storage.local.get(['key'], function(result) {
  console.log('Value currently is ' + result.key);
});
```

You can have more details in the official chrome documentation: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/